# Configuring/Accessing MQQueueConnectionFactory in WAS application

Tags: java, jndi, ibm-mq, ibm-was

I have a library that is giving me a message of com.ibm.mq.MQMessage type, which i add information to then send it in a queue.  I can do this if I create my own MQQueueConnectionFactory in the application, but now I'm trying to set stuff up in WAS console and access in my java webapp via JNDI.  How do I configure a jms resource via WAS console so that I can retrieve a com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory instance via JNDI?  Or how can I send a com.ibm.mq.MQMessage via standard javax.jms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [complete scenario](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.prodconn.doc/infocenter_homepage/mqwas_home.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_8.0.0%2F11&lang=en) demonstrating how to connect an application running in WebSphereApplication server to MQ in the MQ Knowledge Center. That will contain details of how to configure the JMS resources within the WAS admin panels.

There's also one for the [Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/prodconn_1.0.0/com.ibm.prodconn.doc/infocenter_homepage/mqwasliberty_home.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_8.0.0%2F12&lang=en) as well.

**However** the com.ibm.mq.MQMessage is an object from the MQ Java Classes API - and is not a JMS Message. It's worth confirming the exact type here - as the MQ Java Classes should not ideally be used within a JavaEE environment - [see this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266535) for full details.